# Disable multi-window mode for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, multi-window

I am new to unity. I was trying to develop the game of space shooter for android device, and found that in Api24+ the multi-window is ruining the design.

So I have tried to make a custom Manifest by adding the manifest to the directory "Assets/Plugins/Android/" named as AndroidManifest.xml.

As indicated at:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html

Then added the following line `android:resizeableActivity="false"` to disable split screen mode.

As indicated at:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

But nothing happened I still can use multi-window mode in the game.

Edit:

I only added android:resizeableActivity="false" to application and that failed:

```
<application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
```

Comment: The folder names should be capitalized....`Assets\Plugins\Android`

Comment: I have it "Assets\Plugins\Android" just forgot to capitalize them in the post. Fixing it.

Comment: Fixed my problem needed to add android:resizeableActivity="false" to the activity not the application.

Comment: Since that was a typo and now fixed, I just re-opened and renamed it. Please, put the comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added android:resizeableActivity="false" to the activity also solved my problem:

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">
```